# Did any devices use the Commodore 64 joystick ports as outputs or two-way communications ports?

Tags: commodore-64, commodore, joystick, vic-20, input-devices

Looking at the [schematic and explanation of how the C64 joystick
ports work](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/11191/7208), it seems clear that the stick direction and button
lines (`JOYA0`, through `JOYA3` for port 1 and `JOYB0`, through
`JOYB3` for port 2) can also be used as outputs by having the attached
device sense the levels of those lines (5V and 0V) and programming the
CIA to pull the levels high and low in the same way as is done for
keyboard scanning. (Or, for that matter, manually pressing appropriate
keys on the keyboard to bring the levels low.)

This should also work on the VIC-20, and perhaps other Commodore
computers with joystick ports.

Were any devices that used this technique manufactured and sold? If
so, what were they, and how did they deal with keyboard interference
with the scanning?

(This question was inspired by a comment on the pagetable.com blog
post [NES and SNES Controllers on a 6502 (like the C64)](https://www.pagetable.com/?p=1365). It
seems to me that you could use the same technique with NES/SNES
controllers plugged into the joystick ports instead of the user port,
albeit you'd need to deal with the issue of keys pressed on the
keyboard interfering with the I/O.)

Comment: I recall a digital audio sampler for the Amiga using the (C64 compatible) joystick port to record line level input using 8 bit samples at ~8KHz. Most likely the data were sent 4-bits at a time.

Comment: Why not use the Userport instead? It was meant for that sort of things.

Comment: @Janka Well, that's a quite different question only tangentally related to this one. But some reasons could be: 1) leaving the user port free for other peripherals, such as a modem; 2) lower hardware cost (due to cheaper connector and PC board); 3) connector wear (the user port edge connector is more fragile than the joystick connectors); and 4) non-technical users may feel more comfortable plugging and unplugging with the less intimidating joystick port and connector.

Comment: I think the joystick ports are the ones you don't want to use for anything but joysticks as everyone had them. Plus, the internal circuitry didn't feature any EMI protection to the CIA, so most people outright refused to unplug their joysticks and expose the ports. (It was the same for the Userport, but a damaged joystick port meant the box was essentially bricked.)

Comment: @Janka Even if "everyone had joysticks," non-game software that was more likely to use a modem, A/D or other user port device was less likely to use a joystick. Further, even fewer programs needed _two_ joysticks, so a joystick, user port device and "dongle" could all be used together. But this is _really_ not on topic at all for this question; if you want answers about this you should ask a separate question.

Comment: I just gave a real-life example what was typical. You also had two joysticks always connected because of the brittleness of the ports.

Comment: @janka I'm not clear on what your comments have to do with this question. Perhaps you should be posting your own, separate, question, if you have one, or going to a discussion board rather than SE if you want to vent about how you feel certain things that exist are a bad idea?

Comment: Actually, giving reasons why such devices weren't plenty is helpful in the context of your question.

Comment: @janka Perhaps helpful for misdirecting things to what you want to talk about, but no, I have no interest in _how common_ such things were (since they were obviously not) or why you think (or anybody else thinks) one should use the user port instead. I'm interested merely in what devices did use the joystick ports.

Comment: I get it. Though, readers of your question might be interested in it.

Comment: @Janka To clarify to you (again) how SE works: questions should be posted as questions using the "Ask Question" button at the upper right. If you believe it's an interesting question, post it as a question! Or don't, if you agree that it's a tedious side-rant not useful to anyone.

Comment: Comments are meant for improving the question. You'd let my comment pass, ranting about how much it discomforts you instead.

Comment: @Janka If you have any comments that involve improving _this_ question, as opposed to mixing it up with a separate question, I welcome them. Is it not clear to you that "what devices exist that do this" is an entirely different question from "is it a bad idea to do this"?

Comment: Yes. I had made it clear it's by no means obvious one could use the joytick ports for general I/O. It can be done but there are reasons users would not want to do it (all posted above). The question should read: *Taken that it sounds like a good idea, and knowing the mentioned problems, which devices do it **anyways**?*

Comment: @Janka Your assertion that it's not generally obvious that this can be done is unsupported. (I do accept that it's not obvious to _you_, however, if  you're arguing that.) Regardless, it's clear from both the first paragraph of my question and from an answer describing a commerical product _that did this_ that it can be done.

Comment: @Janka Whether it's a good idea or not is your little crusade and nothing to do with my question; I am merely asking what products did this. The answers to that do not change based on anybody's theories about how good or bad an idea it is. 
As to whether or not it's a good idea, that's clearly so unimportant that nobody, not even you, feels it's worth posting a question about it.

Comment: I seriously doubt you know the meaning of *crusade*.

Answer (score 10):

The dongle for the [PaperClip](https://csdb.dk/release/?id=107546) word processor plugged into joystick port 1. [It read bits 0 and 1 from the dongle and wrote bits 2, 3 and 4 to control it.](https://c64preservation.com/index.php/bbs/dm.php?thread=1579)

Keyboard interference probably wasn't an issue with this use case.

Comment: It was imperative that the dongle avoid keyboard interference, but I would think that an alternative dongle design could have exploited the relationship between the joystick and keyboard port if it included a circuit to watch input 0 and briefly assert inputs 1-4 in sequence in response to a rising edge on input 0.  Without the dongle installed, only four rows of the keyboard would work.

Answer (score 5):

The [Inception 8 joysticks adapter](http://www.c64.cz/index.php?static=inception) uses a joystick port for two-way communication between C64 and Inception board. Basically, a program at the C64 would send a command sequence via the joystick port, switches the port to listen and receives the Inception board's reply. In most cases, the information communicated is the state of the joysticks connected to the Inception board, but the board's FPGA can also act as an external math coprocessor.

Comment: Since Inception uses only a single Joystick port, it should also work with a VIC-20, but I'm not aware of any software supporting this. For the C64 there are a couple of games supporting Inception8.

Answer (score 4):

The amazing little [AtariLab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AtariLab) was actually ported to the C64. This included pretty complete I/O, although it was *mostly* used for input. I'm not sure how many, if any, actually shipped.

Answer (score 4):

One prominent example is the "homebrew" EPROM burner Tiny Eprommer, originally published 1984 in [64'er Magazine, Special Issue #84](https://archive.org/details/64er_sonderheft_84/mode/2up). (People are still building/using this device; it's often seen on fx eBay as both kit or assembled product.)

The main board is attached to the user port but as the device needs more GPIO than what the user port provides, a daughter board is connected, with a cable, to the 2 joystick ports, each of which maps to 4 data bus pins on the EPROM. Thus, the device both reads and writes the EPROM's data bus using the control ports.

The keyboard scanning routine does not interfere as long as the host software refrains from calling the kernal routine for keyboard scanning (`$EA86`, typically invoked from the standard `$EA31` interrupt handler), or disables interrupts. However, typing on the keyboard while using CIA1 for I/O is going to cause trouble, as "random" connections between inputs/outpus are being made.

(As a side note, the control ports are neither better or worse protected than the user port - if you check the schematic, you'll find they both connect directly to a CIA chip. There is nothing inherently wrong with interfacing devices through the control ports, but apart from the inconvenience to the user of having to remove controllers, there is also the limitation of keyboard interference, which for some scenarios - like the EPROM burner - can be acceptable. And of course, if you do blow a CIA, you're more likely to notice if it's the one handling the keyboard/control ports. :)

Comment: I wonder why the designers of such a device wouldn't use 74LS373 and/or 74LS374 or equivalent chips for I/O expansion?  Adding one of each such chips would provide 16 extra I/O pins easily, and I would think that would be easier than adding an extra connector and cable.  Wire the main 8 data pins of the user port to the EPROM data bus and the inputs of the 74LS373/374 chips.  Wire one control output wire to the clock/latch inputs of the 74LS373/374 chips, and wire another to the EPROM chip-select.